# How to bold an echo with php

Tags: javascript, php

i would like to bold just an camp on my select but i dont know how

here is here i get the data

```
public function get_clientes()
{
    $sql="SELECT concat(firstname,' ',lastname) as fullname,id_user, card_number FROM amcpcgg_user ORDER BY card_number ASC";

    $clientes=\helpers\common::object_to_array($this->_db->select($sql));

    $ret='';

    foreach ($clientes as $cliente)
    {
    $ret .= "{id:'" . $cliente['id_user'] . "',text:'" . $cliente['card_number'] . ' ' . $cliente['fullname'] ."'},";
    }

    if ($ret!="") $ret=trim($ret,",");

    return $ret;
}
```

and here where i print the data

```
< script type = "text/javascript" >

  $('#cliente').select2({
    allowClear: true,
    multiple: false,
    data: [ <? php echo $data['clientes']; ?> ]
  });

< /script>
```

i would like to bold the $cliente['card_number']

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. What do you mean by `bold` the card number? Do you mean display the text in a bold font?

Comment: yes but im not printing just the card_number im printing the entire querry

Answer (score 0):

Just simple approach to do this is

```
echo "<b>". $cliente['card_number']."</b>";
```

according to your condition you can do something like

```
$card_number = "<b>".$cliente['card_number']."</b>";
```

and pass `$card_number`.

check [here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/e0xr-7v4y)

Comment: but i define the echo here, `"{id:'" . $cliente['id_user'] . "',text:'" . $cliente['card_number'] . ' ' . $cliente['fullname'] ."'},";`  and i cant just echo the card_number

Comment: ill try it, w8 a sec

Comment: `$card_number = "<b>".$cliente['card_number']."</b>";
  
  foreach ($clientes as $cliente)
  {
  $ret .="{id:'" . $cliente['id_user'] . "',text:'" . $card_number . ' ' . $cliente['fullname'] ."'},";
  }` i did this but it just printed the <b></b>

Comment: this is wrong you should create `$card_number = "<b>".$cliente['card_number']."</b>";` inside `foreach`.

Comment: [link](https://gyazo.com/7912a8265140db49037f870482460946) as you can see printing the <b> too